# Update Express.js's local route variables without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I'm using node.js with the express.js framework and EJS to handle the templates.

Here's my route:

```
app.get('/',function(req,res) {
  res.render('index', {
    matches: [],
    status_message: '',
    message: ''
  });
});
```

When I call app.post, I run queries to a database updating variables `'matches'` and `'status_message'`.  How would I update these variables rendered in the page without having the page reload.

For example, if the user provides invalid credentials, I'd like update the `'status_message'` to "Invalid Credentials".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Basically, modern browsers implement a class called `XMLHttpRequest` that can make HTTP requests to HTTP servers. In your client-side Javascript, create an `XMLHttpRequest` object and use it to execute the `post` request to your server. Use the same `XMLHTTPRequest` object to listen for the server response, then do whatever you want with the response, such as updating a `div`.

You tagged this question with ajax so I guess you already know about it, but you didn't mention or ask anything about it in your question. There are tons of examples of this kind of thing online, e.g. [here](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2014/restful-web-app-node-express-mongodb/) that you can try. There's also [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) which you might find easier to use than native AJAX.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I'm still pretty new to all of this stuff, but I'll look into AJAX a little bit more.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!